# When I try to print my array like a matrix my elements get desaligned

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I have this function, that receives a matrix, and I want to print it like a minesweeper field, but for some reason, the elements get like this:

[image]

```c
void display_field(int (&field)[rows][cols])
{

    int conty = 0;
    int contx = -1;
    string letters[11] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","","h","i","j","k"};
    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE-1;i++)
    {
    
        cout << endl;
        for (int j =0;j<SIZE-1;j++)
        {
            if (j==0){
                if (contx != -1)
                {
//                    cout << contx << "";
                }
//                contx += 1; 
            }

            if (i==0){
                cout << " " << letters[conty] << "  ";
                conty += 1; 
            }
            else{
            if (field[i][j] == 1){
                cout << "1️⃣" << "    ";
            }

            if (field[i][j] == 2){
                cout << "2️⃣" << "    ";
            }
            
            if (field[i][j] == 3){
                cout << "3️⃣" << "    ";
            }

            if (field[i][j] == 4){
                cout << "4️⃣" << "    ";
            }

            if (field[i][j] == 5){
                cout << "5️⃣" << "    ";
            }

            if (field[i][j] == 6){
                cout << "6️⃣" << "    ";
            }

            if (field[i][j] == 7){
                cout << "7️⃣" << "    ";
            }

            if (field[i][j] == 8){
                cout << "8️⃣" << "    ";
            }

            if (field[i][j] == BOMB)
            {
                cout << "" << "    ";
            }
            if (field[i][j] == SAFE){
                cout << "" << "    "; 
            }

            }
            

        }
    }
}
```

And the matrix is always like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 9 1 10 10 10
0 1 1 1 10 10 10
0 10 10 10 10 10 10
0 10 10 10 1 1 1
0 10 10 10 2 9 2
0 10 10 10 2 9 2
```

0 is for walls
1 or 2 is the number of bombs
10 is the Safe Squares
9 is the Bomb squares

One thing that I found it is, this happens only if I use the Integrated Terminal on VSCode, but if I use the Code Runner, it works fine.

Comment: Some of your blanks are probably tabs.

Comment: The terminal with the "wrong" output seems to be set up with proportional font; spaces are narrower than non-whitespace characters.

Comment: I cheched, I am not using tabs, and how can I change this, Igor?